# Flutter - APNS token has not been set yet. Please ensure the APNS token is available by calling getAPNSToken()

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

While calling the subscribeToTopic method in iOS, this APNS token exception is coming. I have followed the documentation. I have used the Flutterfire configure command for configuring the Flutter project.

But this error is coming. Anyone know why this error is coming and how to resolve it?

I haven't called the getAPNSToken() method in the code.

Is it needed to initiate this method before calling subscribeToTopic method?

**Note:** We are not using tokens to send notifications to particular users. We are using the topic to send notifications. So I'm not calling the getToken and getAPNSToken methods.

```
1970-01-02 04:49:38.216263+0300 Runner[675:161670] flutter: [firebase_messaging/apns-token-not-set] APNS token has not been set yet. Please ensure the APNS token is available by calling `getAPNSToken()`.
1970-01-02 04:49:38.216725+0300 Runner[675:161670] flutter: #0      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging._APNSTokenCheck (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:138:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:390:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      PushNotificationService.subscribeUserToFirebase (package:team/src/common/notification/firebase/push_notification.dart:70:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      userAPI (package:team/src/features/master_data/application/master_data_providers.dart:116:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FutureHandlerProviderElementMixin.handleFuture.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:riverpod/src/async_notifier/base.dart:337:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: "Please ensure the APNS token is available by calling getAPNSToken()" Have you done that? If no, why not, if yes why don't you say you've done so in your question so people know you are having this issue despite having called that.

Comment: @Piepants I have updated my question. I haven't called getAPNSToken() method in the code. Is it needed to call before subscribeToTopic() method call?

Comment: I added call to getAPNSToken  and I still  have the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/pull/11400) an APNS token needs to be available before calling subscribeToTopic method.

So on the iOS platform, if apnsToken is not available, we have added a delay. After a delay, if we are calling getAPNSToken, it is getting a token. so we can call the subscribeToTopic method.

**Answer Reference**: [Github Issue Comment](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11590#issuecomment-1752226239)

```
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    String? apnsToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getAPNSToken();
    if (apnsToken != null) {
      await _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(personID);
    } else {
      await Future<void>.delayed(
        const Duration(
          seconds: 3,
        ),
      );
      apnsToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getAPNSToken();
      if (apnsToken != null) {
        await _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(personID);
      }
    }
  } else {
    await _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(personID);
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

I added delaly like -

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

An error occurred while calling method Messaging#subscribeToTopic #10625

Comment: This works for me... thanks...

Comment: This is so dumb - but, yes, it works - would be much nicer if Firebase had a call back to let you know it was ready for getToken to be called.

Comment: It didn't help any other solution